# ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow but the cookie is small

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I recently started receiving a `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` from a simple form upload. Looking at the POST request, the Content-Length is 25000+, but the cookie is only 520 characters and contains only the session cookie. ActionDispatch::Cookies::MAX_COOKIE_SIZE is 4096.

This is the form in question. It's an ActiveAdmin sidebar.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<%= form_tag "/import/from_csv", method: :post, multipart: true do %>
  Upload a CSV file.
  <%= label_tag(:file, 'CSV file:') %>
  <%= file_field_tag(:file) %>

  <%= label_tag(:reason, "Default Reason:") %>
  <%= select_tag(:reason,
        options_for_select(Rails.configuration.x.reasons, "unknown")
      )
  %>

  <%= label_tag(:source, "Default Source:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:source, 'csv') %>

  <%= submit_tag("Import",  id: "import") %>
<% end %>
```

We're using the default session store with the JSON cookies serializer. We're not doing anything special with cookies. I tried clearing the cookie, same problem.

What could be causing this?

- Rails 6.1.3.2
- ActiveAdmin 2.9.0
- Ruby 2.7.2
- Devise 4.7.3

Comment: You want to use a different session store, for instance activerecord or memcache. This will solve a lot of issues that may pop up further down the road.

Comment: @NickM Maybe. But I'd like to know first why this is happening. I don't appear to be exceeding the limit.

Comment: It could be that the framework is trying to save something large in the cookie and it doesn't succeed because of the size limit. I've had this happening throughout various applications, it was rather difficult to debug, but stopped happening after I changed the session store.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the cookie value in a debugger, what's happening is each of 50 flashes is being put into the session cookie. This bloats out the session value to just under 4k. Encryption puts it over the line.

I'll switch to session cookies.